React native scrollToEnd doesn't seem to be working
The following scrollToEnd leveraging the messagesListRef isn't working for some reason (There are no errors or warnings either):
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {FlatList, View, Text} from "react-native";

export default function FlatlistComponent(){
 const messagesListRef = useRef(null);

  function messageListHandler(msgsRef) {
    return msgsRef.current.scrollToEnd();
  }

return (
   <FlatList
        ref={messagesListRef}
        onLayout={() => {
           messageListHandler(messagesListRef);
        }}
        data={messagesData}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => messagesWrapper}
        keyExtractor={(message) => message.id}
   />
  )
}

I have tried placing the scrollToEnd call within a useEffect and a setTimeOut on separate occasions but neither of the ideas work.
Also, please note that nearly all the other questions and answers regarding similar issues more or less are very old and involve class components and hence deal with this issue differently. I have tried many of the solutions mentioned in them but none of those work. Kindly do not flag the question as duplicate without comparing the provided code with the code in the supposed solution and if it does match, please add a link to the thread in the comments first. Thanks!

Is the renderItem code proper? I think messagesWrapper should either throw an error or render as if it were not passed any props

Well yes I’ve only passed messagesWrapper as an example here because I felt it is irrelevant. The FlatList components are being rendered exactly as they should be (as they were being rendered prior to attempting to add the scrollToEnd functionality). Like I said, everything seems to be working fine except the scrollToEnd functionality.

Are you trying to scroll to the end of the list whenever messageData changes?

Not yet. That would be the desired next step but the problem right now is I need the users to start at the bottom of the chat lists first (at the latest message). Basically for the chat to scroll to the bottom immediately as they open it. Also, please note that I am aware of the inverted FlatList + reversed data array method mentioned in some of the answers but I do not wish to go down that path.

You can create a function to scroll to the end of a FlatList by using the scrollToEnd method.
This method will works:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);

  const data = Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => `Item ${i + 1}`);

  const scrollToEnd = () => {
    flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{ padding: 200, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#ccc' }}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
      <Button title="Scroll to End" onPress={scrollToEnd} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;


I've been finding that scrollToEnd doesnt always scroll to the end. It could be that when scrollToEnd gets called the most recent item havent fully rendered but idk. A work for this is to scroll to the height provided from the  onContentSizeChange prop (demo):
 <FlatList
  ref={messagesListRef}
  data={messagesData}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <MessagesWrapper item={item} index={index} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(message) => message.id}
  onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => {
    console.log('size change:', height);
    if (shouldScrollToBottom.current)
      messagesListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: height });
  }}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
  pagingEnabled
  bounces={false}
/>


using messageListHandler https://snack.expo.dev/9jylXH_1lgFiXhWsjOZF7

although it works in the demo you've provided, it still doesn’t seem to be working in my project. I tried a couple other variations of your solution as well but still no luck. Thanks anyway and please let me know if you find anything else.
